# Actualizar campos dinámicamente con Jquery y AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo una tabla que la consulto con PHP. Uno de los campos de cada registro es booleano, el cual si es OK, lo muestro con un glyphicons y si no es OK le pongo otro glyphicons. El tema es que me gustaría que al hacerle click al glyphicons lo activase o desactivase, es decir, que sea OK o no OK sin refrescar la página. Estoy viendo varios ejemplos de cómo hacerlo con jquery y AJAX pero no consigo que funcione nada... hay uno de ellos que consigo que haga el update en un php externo pero tengo que refrescar la página para poder ver los cambios... algún ejemplo disponible? gracias

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $(function() {

  $('#btnSi, #btnNo').on('click', function(e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var activo = elem.text();
    var id = elem.val();
    var url = 'colleges_save2.php';
    e.preventDefault();
    var request = $.ajax({
      data: {id: id, activo:activo},
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(text) {
      console.log(text);
      if (text == "exitoso") {
        if (activo == '1') {
          elem.removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
          //elem.text('1');
        } else {
          elem.removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove');
          //elem.text('0');
        }
      }
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Error de petición: " + textStatus);
    });

  });

});
```

college_save2.php

```
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
<?php include('session.php');  
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $data = explode("-",$_POST['id']); 
        $campo = $data[0]; // nombre del campo
        $id = $data[1]; // id del registro 
        $value = $data[2]; // valor por el cual reemplazar 


        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE applications SET ".$campo." = '".$value."' 
WHERE id_application = '".$id."'" ); 
            //$sql = "UPDATE applications SET `activo`='$activo' WHERE `id`='$id'";
echo ("exitoso");

?>
```

Comment: Podrías colocar tu código de ejemplo, un fragmento de lo que tienes. Sería mucho más fácil teniendo en cuenta que la respuesta sería mas precisa.

Comment: He colocado mi JS que intenté usar con un href pero no tengo manera de que funcione...

Comment: La variable activo == '1' no deberia ser la que venga de la respuesta del archivo php?

Comment: Por lo que he entendido, cada glyphicon tiene el id "btnSi". Quieres que al hacer click en él, éste cambie entre "ok" y "remove", para entrar bien en contexto es un input? un span? button? Que es "btnSi".

Comment: Es una variable que toma el valor 1, activado o 0 desactivado... no me gustaría hacerlo con button ya que quiero que en la tabla tan solo aparezca el glyphicon

Comment: @GerardoPacheco cuando hago la consulra en la tabla ya me muestra en cada registro si tiene ese alumno tiene el campo el 1 o 0 (me lo muestra con un glyphicon... y sin refrescar me gustaría switchearlo. Gracias

Comment: Creo que el error lo tienes en la 3era linea var $elem = $(#btnSi); deberia ser var $elem = $('#btnSi');

Comment: @GerardoPacheco lo he probado y sigue sin funcionar... sería posible llamarlo con un href?

Comment: Ya he conseguido que me funcione bien pero el problema es que me refresca la página... no me actualiza el glyphon sino que es como si le dieses a F5

Comment: Yo lo que haría, es eliminar el elemento que tienes creado con`remove()` y después crearía otro de la misma manera... acuerdate que en javascript todo es **live** por así decirlo... y sucede que algunas cosas pueden hacerse en milisegundos en el caso de ajax y pueden tambien no hacerse porque no es sincrono

Comment: inlcuso eliminando el elemento remove sigue refrescando toda la página... llevo mas de dos horas toqueteando y nada...

Comment: ahh!! ya me di cuenta, en tu evento  `.on('click', function()` pasa una variable a la función y después utilízala para prevenir el comportamiento normal de un clic, que en ese caso es "hacer un tipo submit", es decir, `.on('click', function(e)` y después dentro de la función `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Cig has dado en el clavo... funciona sin refrescar. Ahora tan solo tengo un problemilla que es que solo puedo usar la función una sola vez con ese registro, es decir si está en 1 o en 0 y le doy click me cambia el estado a 0 o 1... hasta ahí bien... el caso es que si le vuelvo a dar no hace nada... en los demás registros mientras le de una vez sola funcina!

Comment: @Vieira revisa si el clic se esta llamando con un `console.log` después revisa que estas enviando mediante ajax y que recibes.

Comment: @Cig recibo "exitoso" o "noexitoso". Llamo a la función con <button id="btnSi" value="application-<?php echo $id_appl ?>-0" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green"></button>

Comment: @Vieira en tu `done` revisa que tiene activo, creo que por ahí esta el problema

Comment: @Cig es lo que tengo arriba request.done(function(text) console.log me da "exitoso o "noexitoso"

Comment: Lo más posible es la cache del elemento, a lo mejor si lo este haciendo. Entonces creo que seria conveniente que utilices remove para estar seguro. Como consejo, trata de no utilizar `text()` como un parametro de comparación, dado que el html se puede modificar. Utiliza una variable como `data` o algo parecido. Slds

Comment: creo que lo que pasa es lo siguiente por lo que he podido averiguar... la tabla me muestra efectivamente el campo actualizado pero creo que el problema proviene del <button> ya que haciendo alerts en las variables veo que al volver a darle al <button> me envía los mismos datos de la primera vez, por eso no lo vuelve a cambiar. Quizás lo que hay que refrescar con algun div es el <button> no crees?